# Host Header Value Not Working Externally

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis

This is a really strange issue. The host header value of myapplication.mywebsite.com works fine within the internal network. But when people from outside the network try accessing it, it routes people to the default web application in IIS. An A ref was definately made, and external pinging does show it is going to the right IP addresss. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specifically mention the website in question, I'd recommend using a program such as wfetch.exe to find out what's REALLY going on.

WFETCH.EXE will allow you to see everything from the DNS resolution to the request to the HTTP headers, etc returned.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284285

Answer (score 1):

Is the applicaiton hosted on your network? Do you have a firewall or other device between the internet users and your app that could be stripping, or altering the host headers? Also are you sure that the site in IIS is listening for the host header on the right IP, or is it just listening on the internal IP.

Answer (score 1):

IIS is probably listening for the host header on the wrong IP.